# Export Attlassian Confluence wiki to a PDF

Tags: pdf, confluence

I would like to write a book (about a software) so it is a kind of technical documentation with source code, quotes, links & diagrams ..etc

I love FOSS and I am a Linux user since 12 years, may be the only negative point that I've always noticed is the office suite (libre & open office).

I decided to use Confluence, it is a very good software. And I would like to know if I can export a confluence wiki to an e-book (PDF & epub) that I can publish later.

Is it feasible to use Confluence to write e-books ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. Yes, because Confluence is able to export wiki spaces directly to PDF. No, because you normally want to do some styling and define the order of the export, which is not so easy with Confluence. There are some additional plugins available for Confluence, I know that [Scroll EPUB Exporter](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.k15t.scroll.scroll-epub) allows to export (with some advanced features) directly to PDF.

So you should give it a try, and see if it is sufficient for you.